# Activity as rewarded item in Admob rewarded video

Tags: android, android-activity, rewardedvideoad

Android Studio noob here, I try to implement rewarded video ad in my game, my reward item is an activity. I was able to to implementing it. However, in the end of video ad, it automatically bring user to the reward activity.

My intention is, i don't want it automatic, i need the ad keep visible until users click the video ad close button.

this is my rewarditem code:

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intgame=new Intent(MainActivity.this,RewardActivity.class);
    startActivity(intgame);
}
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated..

thanks.

Comment: Put that code to start the activity in the onRewardedVideoAdClosed()

Comment: the problem if i put the code in the onRewardedVideoAdClosed() is user doesn't have to watch the ad until finish, they can enter the reward activity immediately after they close the Ad

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public int adHasBeenSeen = 0;

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    adHasBeenSeen = 1;
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed(){
    if(adHasBeenSeen == 1){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intgame=new Intent(MainActivity.this,RewardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intgame);
        adHasBeenSeen = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onRewarded` callback, set a flag which indicated the user must be rewarded.

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    mustBeRewarded = true;
}
```

Now while closing the ad, inside `onRewardedVideoAdClosed` callback, start your activity

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    if(mustBeRewarded){
        Intent intgame=new Intent(MainActivity.this,RewardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intgame);
    }
}
```